# How can I make a linux command wait for the end of input before piping?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe, cat

I find myself often using linux shell commands, such as `grep`, `sed` and `awk`, to format/filter/forward stuff into something more useable.

The "source" data is usually the output of a process, or the `cat` of a local file.

As I'm becoming more fluent with the commands, I find myself using them more and more. What I used to do before with a notepad++ regex-search&replace, I now know how to do "on the fly" in my shell.

The "issue" I'm now encountering is how to deal with data I've "copied" from another source, which I want to feed into the shell directly via stdin, and the output I only want to see in stdout. The problem I'm encountering is that there is a "criss-cross" of the input and output. For example:

```
>awk '$1 == "true" {print $2}'
true Paul
Paul
false John        
true Janice
Janice
```

The issue is that this is not useable for me. I need the output to come clearly separated from the input. Either it comes afterwards, or I don't want to see stdin at all.

How could we do that? I've found I can use `tail` to "hold" the input data until it's all been fed:

```
tail -n 999 | awk '$1 == "true" {print $2}'
true Paul
false John
true Janice
Paul
Janice
```

This works, but is a little bit cumbersome.

Are there any built-in commands that basically "hold" the stream until it is over (or rather, don't print anything until all input has been processed)? Or ways to simply suppress seeing stdin? I could also use temp files, but I'd like to have a "clean 1 step no overhead" way of doing it...

Comment: Would you add how you're "copying" the data? Directly piping output, including catting a file (you know you can just redirect stdin, or for most command list the file on the command line, right?) shouldn't have the issue you're seeing.

Comment: If I undderstand your question, you can use the shell `here` document for this. `awk '....' <<EOD dataline1 dataline2 datalineN EOD` Where you have typed in your `awk '....' <<` then paste in your data, the on separate line, type `EOD`. Your output should comeout, with the input in the screen above it. Good luck.

Comment: When I'm typing at the command line like that, I like the immediate feedback.  If the interleaved output is no use, it means it is going to a file or pipe and the interleaving isn't a problem anyway.  Roughly, on those (fairly rare) occasions when I'm typing the data, the immediate throughput is a benefit.  Using a command to buffer a copy of the input is reasonable.  I note that `sort` is a command that must read all its input before it generates any output.  However, there are other reasons why `sort` is not generally suitable (such as the fact it reorders data).

Comment: > Would you add how you're "copying" the data?
Basically, I'm just pasting from the clipboard.
> If I undderstand your question, you can use the shell here document for this.
That works very nicely too. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '$1 == "true" {print $2}' | tac | tac
```

or

```
awk '$1 == "true" {print $2}' > /tmp/file.txt; cat /tmp/file.txt
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the "tac" command. This solution is similar to may "tail" trick, but (arguably) cleaner. I also like it, because you can easily `alias tacat='tac | tac`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any such command, but you can easily add your own in `.bashrc`:

```
waiting() {
  printf "%s\n" "$(cat)"
}
```

then

```
awk '$1 == "true" {print $2}' | waiting
```

You can of course also put `waiting` first if you prefer.

Comment: Seems to do exactly what I asked for. I'm not sure how it's working, but I'll accept it :)